How to open LXterminal and running a command at desktop login
I am ready to rip my hair out.
I've found several tutorials including a nice flowchart that confirms I should be using one of the many autostart functions yet not enough documentation on how to run them the way I need to.
So I've surmised that the directories typically don't exist on raspbian until you create them.
'''
mkdir /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart/
'''
So now we have our directories created we create a new .desktop file that should execute:
'''
nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart/kiosk.desktop
'''
and I'm just a simple person trying to run the following bash script so lets save the following in the .desktop file:
'''
@lxterminal /home/pi/Kiosk.sh
'''
so lets make sure we have kiosk.sh:
'''
nano /home/pi/kiosk.sh
'''
'''
#!/bin/bash/
ffplay /dev/video0 -fs
'''
save as kiosk.sh
lets check if it runs:
''' reboot -i'''
and nothing!

I guess i have the following questions:
are the various autostart directories actually supposed to be directories, what are they supposed to contain, does every .desktop file get executed in the directory, and how do you call lxterminal from within this desktop file?

I found this post https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=294014 which states that autostart is a file, not a directory. To run a script, it should contain @bash /path/my_script .
